# When something is put into play, who controls it and why?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It seems to me that the underlying assumption with [Hive Stirrings](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hive%20Stirrings) is that the Sliver tokens come into play under your control. However, I am building a random standard Polymorph deck (random standard is like t2 but sets are picked randomly) which could also use [Defense of the Heart](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Defense%20of%20the%20Heart) as a 4-8 copy of polymorph if I could give my opponent the slivers instead.

Can anyone point me to some kind of reasoning/ruling behind which player the tokens come out under because to me this seems like kind of an oversight on the part of the card creators by not being specific enough with the card wording.

Comment: Can whomever voted to closed as unclear explain your confusion, so that the author may at least have a chance to clarify? The question looks clear to me.

Comment: There is a mini-cycle of "hunted" creatures from Ravnica: City of Guilds that give your opponents tokens. This link will show you them: http://magiccards.info/query?q=hunted&v=card&s=cname Hunted Troll is in color with Defense of the Heart.

Comment: @Rainbolt I VTC'd as I was unclear what the question, or problem, was. (You're right I should have left a comment.) Gendolkari apparently noticed it, but I couldn't. Now with the edit it's clearer, I guess the asker's just confused because Hive Stirrings doesn't say the Slivers enter under _their own_ control. (So theoretically you can give them to anyone, right?)

Answer (score 4):

The tokens will always come into play under your control, you cannot choose otherwise.

From the comprehensive rules:

> 110.2a If an effect instructs a player to put an object onto the battlefield, that object enters the
>   battlefield under that player’s control unless the effect states otherwise.
>
> 110.5a A token is both owned and controlled by the player under whose control it entered the
>   battlefield.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was assuming.  Sucks that I'm stuck with only 4 cards of the combo but whatever.

Comment: Funny sidenote; Tokens used to be owned by the owner of the effect that put them into play, not the player by whose control it entered the battlefield. This however changed since M10 rules change, which broke some quite funny combo's